# Kan extension and singular cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, model-categories, kan-extensions

Let $Sm$ denote the category of smooth manifolds and $Top$ the category of topological spaces. Then we have a faithful functor $Sm\rightarrow Top$ which gives a functor
$$Ho(Sm)\rightarrow Ho(Top).$$
We know that the homtopy category of topological spaces is equivalent to the homotopy category of CW-complexes. In particular, since CW-complexes are the colimits of spheres, that means that $Ho(Sm)$ is dense in $Ho(Top)$. I'm wondering if we can use this to define the singular cohomology. Assume we have defined the singular cohomology of smooth manifolds. Is there a natural way to extend this functor from $Ho(Sm)^{op}$ to $Ho(Top)^{op}$? The most natural way I know to extend a functor is the Kan extension. Does this do the job? Or is there another way?

Comment: The functor is in fact fully faithful, but I'm not sure what you say is true : colimits in $Ho(Top)$ are usually very weird and do *not* coincide with homotopy colimits in general.

Comment: What is $Ho(Sm)$ actually meant to be?

Comment: CW complexes are not colimits of spheres, they are colimits involving disks, spheres, and CW complexes of 1 dimension lower. Perhaps this can be turned into just colimits involving disks and spheres.

Comment: What is true is that in the special case of singular cohomology, the value on the spheres is enough to determine the cohomology theory. You essentially construct your CW complex by the skeleta of your CW complex, and the quotients are all wedges of spheres which forces the cohomology theory to coincide with the usual cellular cohomology.

Comment: Which model structure do you use on $Top$?

Comment: As it turns out, by general nonsense derived functors defined using functorial factorisations of a model structure have the universal property of _absolute_ Kan extensions, which are pointwise a fortiori. But these are Kan extensions along the universal functor from a model category to its homotopy category, rather than the inclusion of a subcategory of the homotopy category. Incidentally, $\operatorname{Ho} \textbf{Top}$ is not concrete, so you won’t find any small dense subcategory there...